# How to send and retrieve object in knockout js on submit ?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have some fields in my form i want to display them as a grid on another page. What will be the best solution for it ?
Or can i do it as one page application ?
here is my html code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="knockout-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wireframe.css"/>

</head>
<body>
<div class="wireframe">
<h3 class="table-head">Table Header</h3>
<div id="addbranchdiv" class="span12">
        <span class=span8>
            <button type="button" class=" button branchbtn" id="brancharea">Branch Areas</button>
        </span>
        <span class="span4">
            <a class=" button branchbtn" id="addbranch" href="wireframe3.html" target="_blank">Add Branch Areas</a> 
        </span>
    </div> 
<div class="container" class="span12">


<div class="table-heading grayhead" >
        <div class="field1">
            <label class="row-label">Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field2">
            <label class="row-label">Description</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field3">
            <label class="row-label">Template</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field4">
            <label class="row-label">Meta-Keyword</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field5">
            <label class="row-label">Meta-Description</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field6">
            <label class="row-label">Meta-Title</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field7">
            <label class="row-label">Meta-Enable Search</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field8">
            <label class="row-label">Actions</label>
        </div>
</div>
<div data-bind='foreach: formIndex'>
    <div class="table-row white" >
        <div class="">
            <input data-bind="value:name">
        </div>
        <div class="field2">
            <input data-bind="value:description">
        </div>
        <div class="field3">
            <input data-bind="value:template">
        </div>
        <div class="field4">
            <input data-bind="value:metakeyword">
        </div>
        <div class="field5">
            <input data-bind="value:metadescription">
        </div>
        <div class="field6">
            <input data-bind="value:metatitle">
        </div>

          <span><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeField'>Delete</a></span>
    </div>
    </div>
  <button data-bind='click: addField'>Add Field</button>
    <button data-bind='enable: formIndex().length > 0' type='submit'>Submit</button>    
</div>
<div id="save" class="span12">
        <button type="button"  id="savebtn" class="button"  >Save</button> 
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is script

```
<script>
var FormModel = function(formIndex) {
    var self = this;
    self.formIndex = ko.observableArray(formIndex);

    self.addField = function() {
        self.formIndex.push({
            name: "",
            description: "",
            template:"",
            metakeyword:"",
            metadescription:"",
            metatitle:"",
        });
    };

    self.removeField = function(field) {
        self.formIndex.remove(field);
    };

    self.save = function(form) {
        alert("Could now transmit to server: " + ko.utils.stringifyJson(self.formIndex));
        // To actually transmit to server as a regular form post, write this: ko.utils.postJson($("form")[0], self.formIndex);
    };
};

var viewModel = new FormModel([
    { name: "Tall Hat", description: "39.95",template: "12",metakeyword:"meta",metadescription:"",metatitle:"metatitle"},
    { name: "Long Cloak", description: "120.00",template:"12",metakeyword:"meta",metadescription:"",metatitle:"metatitle"},
      { name: "Tall Hat", description: "39.95",template: "12",metakeyword:"meta",metadescription:"",metatitle:"metatitle"},
    { name: "Long Cloak", description: "120.00",template:"12",metakeyword:"meta",metadescription:"",metatitle:"metatitle"}
]);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

// Activate jQuery Validation
$("form").validate({ submitHandler: viewModel.save });


</script>
```

I want to send object on click of submit and retrieve it on another page how can it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it. The simplest of which would be to keep the grid on the same view and hide the form and show the grid when you click the submit button. 
Another way would be to store the information you need to retrieve in local storage (you could use something like amplify js for this) and then pass the key as parameter to the other page, retrieve the information and delete the storage key, then display the grid with the appropriate values.
If the form is submitting the data to the server, then the serve can redirect to the grid page and pass the values (depending on how you render the html). Hope that helps.

Comment: But there is a option of edit also when i click on it then open the form with the same values so when i change the values it reflect on the grid. do you know any example of this scenario ?